# Getting an updated variable value from inside a click/change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, onchange

I am having an issue doing simple addition with two variables `calPrice` and `tpPrice`. I am defining the variables first and then within the click functions I am getting data from inputs and redefining the variable. So, when I do `var totalPrice = calPrice + tpPrice;`, why would the new defined values not print anything?

Let's say the data for `calPrice` is 10 and `tpPrice` is 5 once the click/change function has ran...why doesn't my `totalPrice` variable pick up these values?

```
var calPrice;
var tpPrice;

$('.calendar-check').on('click', function() {
  calPrice = [];
  $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function() {
    calPrice.push($(this).data('cal-price'));
  });
  $('#pg-price-review').html("$ " + calPrice);
});

$('.tp-pack-check').on('change', function() {
  tpPrice = [];
  $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function() {
    tpPrice.push($(this).data('price'));
  });
  $('#tp-cost-review').html("$" + tpPrice);
});

var totalPrice = calPrice + tpPrice;
$('#package-review-total').html(totalPrice);
```

Comment: why isn't the code for total price inside the Event handler. You need to calculate the `totalPrice` after the values are updated int he event handlers. The value of `totalPrice` isn't evaluated after the first evaluation which would be `undefined`

Comment: Your `totalPrice` value is only calculated when the page loads, and both the `calPrice` and `tpPrice` variables are empty. You need to instead calculate that value within the `click` handlers. Although you should note that both of those variables hold arrays, so I'm not sure what behaviour you're expecting the `+` operator to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these arrays *tpPrice* and *calPrice* contains numbers, you can sum up and format both at the end of those click/change event-handlers.

Furthermore in this example [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) are used for following purpose:

- Array.prototype.reduce():

  Can sum up numeric elements, like:

  ```
  [1,2].reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;}, 0) => 3
  ```
- Array.prototype.map():

  Creates another array that might contain different elements, like

  ```
  [1.23, 4.56].map(function(ele){return '$'+ele; }) => ["$1.23", "$4.56"]
  ```
- Array.prototype.join():

  Can join array elements together with certain signs, like

  ```
  [1,2].join("+") => "1+2"
  ```

This might help you:

```
var calPrice = [];
var tpPrice = [];
$('.calendar-check').on('click', function() {
  calPrice = [];
  $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function() {
    calPrice.push($(this).data('cal-price'));
  });
  var pgPrizeTotal = sumUpArray(calPrice);
  $('#pg-price-review').html('$'+pgPrizeTotal +' = '+ formatArray(calPrice));
  calcTotalPrize();
});

$('.tp-pack-check').on('change', function() {
  tpPrice = [];
  $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function() {
    tpPrice.push($(this).data('price'));
  });
  var tpPrizeTotal = sumUpArray(tpPrice);
  $('#tp-cost-review').html('$'+ tpPrizeTotal +' = '+ formatArray(tpPrice));
  calcTotalPrize();
});

function formatArray(array){
    return array.map(function(ele){return '$'+ele; }).join("+");
}

function sumUpArray(array){
    return array.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b;}, 0);
}

function calcTotalPrize(){
    var totalPrice = sumUpArray(calPrice) + sumUpArray(tpPrice);
    $('#package-review-total').html('$'+ totalPrice);
}
```

Comment: This gives this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

Comment: edit the start to be: var calPrice = []; var tpPrice = []; as per my answer should work.

Comment: Might not be an issue, but reduce is IE9+ comparable only, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: What does the map function do?

Comment: It creates another array that contains strings that might look like this: $1.23, $3.56. and these strings are finally joined together with +

Comment: And by following @Hubert Grzeskowiak 's excellent answer, the prize- and cost-reviews could also look like this. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the order of execution in your code.

Most of your statements are function calls of jQuery's `on(...)` which register a function as callback on events. The function you are passing there is run once the event occurs.

Your `var totalPrice = calPrice + tpPrice;` line however, is run once at the beginning, when all event listeners are defined and registered (but not triggered).

What you need to do is put the last two lines into every function that changes either of your variables `calPrice` or `tpPrice`. To make things more maintainable, put these two lines into a new function called `updateTotal` and call it from within the other functions.

---

Aside from that I think your price calculation is wrong. You are defining an array and pushing data into it. This does not sum the values. Printing the contents of the array in HTML will yield the values comma separated. What you rather want to do is parsing the data as a number (e.g. float) and add them together.

Answer (score 1):

calPrice and tpPrice area arrys. You cannot total the arrays by:

```
var totalPrice = calPrice + tpPrice;
```

Maybe:

```
var totalPrice = = 0;

for(var i = 0; i<= calPrice.length; i++)
  totalPrice += calPrice[i];

for(var j = 0; j<= tpPrice.length; j++)
  totalPrice += tpPrice[j];
```

Edit: Full code in the right order:

```
var calPrice = [];
var tpPrice = [];

function setTotal() {
    var totalPrice = = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<= calPrice.length; i++)
      totalPrice += calPrice[i];

    for(var j = 0; j<= tpPrice.length; j++)
      totalPrice += tpPrice[j];

    $('#package-review-total').html(totalPrice);
}

$('.calendar-check').on('click', function() {
  calPrice = [];
  $('.calendar-check:checked').each(function() {
    calPrice.push($(this).data('cal-price'));
  });
  $('#pg-price-review').html("$ " + calPrice);
   setTotal();
});

$('.tp-pack-check').on('change', function() {
  tpPrice = [];
  $('.tp-pack-check:checked').each(function() {
    tpPrice.push($(this).data('price'));
  });
  $('#tp-cost-review').html("$" + tpPrice);
  setTotal();
});
```

Comment: And as per Hubert Grzeskowiak this must be called after each event!